# How can I fix my out of index errors after I've capped the max index at the length of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm working with two lists and trying to do so linearly. I have to look at each list element. To go through the first list, I've used a for loop. Then I nested a second loop--tried both for and while--to iterate through my second list. I'm trying to sort the lists into a bigger sorted list as I iterate over each list element. I used a counter to index the second list. When going through the second list, I keep getting an 'out of index' error, despite trying to limit the highest index value to the length of the second list.

TLDR--Why do I keep getting an out of index error when I specified the highest index it should look to as the length of the list?

Working through google excercises with lists, code below:

```
# E. Given two lists sorted in increasing order, create and return a merged
# list of all the elements in sorted order. You may modify the passed in lists.
# Ideally, the solution should work in "linear" time, making a single
# pass of both lists.
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
    x = []
    j = 0
    for item1 in list1:
        print("1\t", str(item1))
        while item1 >= list2[j] and j < len(list2):
            x.append(list2[j])
            j += 1
        x.append(item1)
```

I've been getting the following error:

```
in linear_merge
    while item1 >= list2[j] and j < len(list2):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's the problem attempted with for loops:

```
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
    x = []
    j = 0
    for item1 in list1:
        print("1\t", str(item1))
        for item2 in list2[j:]:
            print("2\t", str(item2))
            if item1 >= item2:
                x.append(item2)
                if j <= len(list2):
                    j += 1
            else:
                x.append(item1)
    return x
```

What error am I making with the indices? Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of the two tests:

```
while j < len(list2) and item1 >= list2[j]:
```

This way, if `j` is out of range, the second test won't be evaluated.

Comment: Why does the order of the tests matter for the while loop to run? Since it's not an `or` won't it still exit the while loop regardless of the order of the tests, so long as one is false?

Comment: Obviously not, or you wouldn't be here.  Your problem isn't stopping the loop; your problem is avoiding the out of bounds error.

Comment: Your second question: No. The first question: Python, like many other languages, uses "short-cut evaluation" in logical expressions. In an `and` expression, if the first sub-condition is false, the entire condition is necessarily false and there is no need to evaluate the second sub-condition. (And your `while` loop stops when the entire condition evaluates to False.) This short-cut also has the advantage of doing things like this very answer: the first sub-condition can prevent an index error in the second sub-condition. This feature is frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

You should change places of 2 tests in this condition:

```
while item1 >= list2[j] and j < len(list2):
```

to:

```
while j < len(list2) and item1 >= list2[j]:
```